# how to run pytest for keras sourcecode

Tags: python, keras, anaconda, travis-ci, pytest

I'm developing a custom layer for the Keras framework and would like to extend their existing testsuite.

Since I'm working on the keras sourcecode, I have installed it like this:

- `pip install keras-preprocessing`
- `pip install keras-applications`
- `git clone https://github.com/keras-team/keras`
- `cd keras`
- `export PYTHONPATH=$PWD:$PYTHONPATH`

After these commands, you are in the cloned keras repository, this is the working directory for the code samples below.

To begin with, I would like to run the existing tests and see what they do. [It looks like](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/590aa832680641218b233b22fa8b3bd7fdc0287e/tests/keras/layers/wrappers_test.py#L636) they can simply be run as a python file:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pytest.main([__file__])
```

But this:

```
python tests/keras/layers/wrappers_test.py
```

produces the following output, and doesn't run any tests

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
usage: wrappers_test.py [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...]
wrappers_test.py: error: unrecognized arguments: -n tests/keras/layers/wrappers_test.py
  inifile: /home/lhk/programming/keras/pytest.ini
  rootdir: /home/lhk/programming/keras
```

So I tried explicitly calling pytest next:

```
pytest tests/keras/layers/wrappers_test.py
```

Exactly the same response (without the tensorflow log):

```
usage: pytest [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...]
pytest: error: unrecognized arguments: -n tests/keras/layers/wrappers_test.py
  inifile: /home/lhk/programming/keras/pytest.ini
  rootdir: /home/lhk/programming/keras
```

I'm using PyCharm, and if I run the tests from within pycharm (which I admittedly tried first), it only produces the messages above.

Apparently, I'm not configuring it correctly. Pytest is not able to pick up the test suite. To find a reference configuration, I looked at the Keras CI setup. They use Travis and the config is opensource: https://travis-ci.org/keras-team/keras/jobs/442252422/config

It looks like I have all the dependencies installed. And the actual test command is basically what I have already tried:

```
PYTHONPATH=$PWD:$PYTHONPATH py.test tests/ --ignore=tests/integration_tests --ignore=tests/test_documentation.py --ignore=tests/keras/legacy/layers_test.py --cov-config .coveragerc --cov=keras tests/
```

It produces the exact same output as above.

I assume that the problem lies with pytest. But the installation section of their automated testing simply shows `pip install pytest pytest-pip8`. I ran this, but sure enough, `requirement already satisfied`.

How can I execute the keras pytests.
I'm running ubuntu 18.04.1, python 3.6.5 with anaconda 64bit.

Comment: You are missing `pytest` plugins that are used for testing; looks like you didn't install all of the test deps. Checking `keras`' setup script, they have `tests` extras defined, so issue `pip install --editable .[tests]` for a simple way (also, you won't need to adjust `PYTHONPATH` after that command), or just install the test packages explicitly: `pip install pytest pytest-pep8 pytest-xdist pytest-cov pytest-timeout pandas requests`.

Comment: @hoefling, finally got around to testing this. If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running the `keras` tests is mentioned on the [Contributing](https://keras.io/contributing/) page:

> Run our test suite locally. It's easy: from the Keras folder, simply run: `py.test tests/`.
>
> <sup>You will need to install the test requirements as well: `pip install -e .[tests]`.</sup>

If you don't want to install the package in editable mode, just install all of the test dependencies explicitly. [Looking at `keras`' setup script](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/2.2.4/setup.py#L44), the command for that would be:

```
$ pip install pytest pytest-pep8 pytest-xdist pytest-cov pytest-timeout pandas requests
```